# Include CSS/JS only when necessary

Tags: php

My menu system all comes from the index file. A simplified example:

```
#index.php
...
<div id="container">
include($inc_file) //index.php?site=news will show news.php
</div>
...
```

My question is: how can I only include some js-files and css-files when they are needed. For example, I have a file with a slider. I would like only to include the js/css-files related to the slider when visiting that page.

I know that I can make if/else clauses, but I find that a bit ineffective. Is it possible to place a session containing an array with all the files that should be included on the frontpage?

Comment: Since this is really a question about how to optionally include files in PHP, I've removed both the javascript and css tags.

Comment: ineffective? why that?

Comment: @RobRaisch Agreed, my mistake.

Comment: @Akam: ineffective might be the wrong word to use. I would just find it more easy to keep the includes inside the single files. But if that isn't possible, I will simply make some if/else clauses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just have a preset array for each page with an array of css/js files it would need to include.
eg.
**settings.php**

```
<?php

$pages = array();

$pages['index'] = array(
    "css" => array("main.css","index.css"),
    "js"  => array("jquery.min.js","someotherjs.js")
);

$pages["about"] = array(
  ...
);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

include('settings.php');


?>
...
<head>
    <?php
        foreach($pages['index']['css'] as $css)
            echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$css'>";
    ?>

    ...
    <?php
        foreach($pages['index']['js'] as $js)
            echo "<script src='$js'></script>";
    </body>
</head>
```

Comment: i wonder why the downvote? and don't forget to accept whichever answer you use @hskrijelj

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would use:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

if ($filename === "somepage") {
?>
<script src=""></script>
<link ...>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I know this method. I was fishing for another solution. However, if what I am searching for isn't possible, I will go with this method, and you will get the approval.

Comment: I dont see how a session is going to help you here. Not using any if/else condition, is going to be tough for including sources CINDITIONALLY. or perhaps I just lack the imagination ;)

Comment: You could theoratically have a template specific source includions, so its not in if else, but it wont be in session either, and I dont think it will be beneficial.

Comment: It is possible in one or another way, but I think that i'll have to do some major changes to make it happend. The file can be includes earlier only to gather the session, but it's not a good solution. I'll go with the if/else.

Comment: i dont think sessions and includes are more efficient than a couple of ifs, but im not sure.

Answer (score -2):

This may not be the answer you were expecting but did you know that the browser does not download `css` or `js` files that have not changed since the last time they were downloaded. They are cached on the client PC and only refreshed if the copy on the server has changed.

Theerfore you may not need to be so selective about what you load on each page as it probably wont cause a fresh download of a css or js file.

Comment: I know that. However, I don't need some js to be downloaded in the first place, if it isn't going to be used.

Answer (score -2):

Prepare an object where you can add style or js files as you need, here a little example.

```
class head {

    private styles = array();
    private scripts = array();

    public function __construct() {}

    // add script in page
    public function add_script(filepath){
       array_push($this->scripts, filepath);
    }

    // add style in page
    public function add_style(filepath){
       array_push($this->styles, filepath);
    }

    // get html <link> for styles
    public function get_styles(){
       $html = '';
       $len = count($this->styles);
       for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
           $html .='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$this->styles[$i].'">'; 
       }
       return $html;
    }

    // get html <script> for scripts
    public function get_scripts(){
       $html = '';
       $len = count($this->scripts);
       for($i=0; $i < $len; $i++){
           $html .='<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$this->scripts[$i].'"></script>'; 
       }
       return $html;
    }

 }
 // destruct ...
```

in your controller :

```
require('/class/head.php');
$head = new head();
$head->add_style('/css/myStyle.css');
$head->add_script('/js/myScript.js');
```

in head

```
<?php echo $head->get_styles(); ?>
<?php echo $head->get_scripts(); ?>
```

Comment: Never thought of using OOP for this, but I'll consider it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Object oriented design patterns is good, the code above is not: 1. SYntax error at variable declaration, 2. empty "constructor" (Which btw is not a real constructor, since its `__construct` in php), 3. String concatenated HTML, 4. Your function returns nothing.